# VS Code Intellisense can't find any classes and extensions not already included (List, ToListAsync, etc.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

We have VS Code Intellisense working, but it only finds methods that are already included via Using statements.  We use certain functions like `.ToListAsync()` and classes like `List` all the time and would like them to appear in the Intellisense list so we don't need to manually add Using statements every time.  (This is also an issue with Visual Studio.)

Is there a way to indicate that there are libraries we always want to appear in Intellisense lists, even if we haven't imported them yet?  There's a list of `using` statements automatically added to new files, but that's not very useful for this purpose b/c they are always pruned on commit.

In TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

This VS Code setting enables auto-import via `using` statements:

> **Omnisharp**: Enable Import Completion

It appears this is the [parallel setting for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/show-imports?view=vsmac-2022):

> Show import items